# Fixed image max width

Tags: html

I have an image `<img>` in `<td></td>` tags, i want to set max fixed width, beacause when image is large, it goes out from layout and my table became to large. And if the image width  is less then max width, it should have original size param. 
How can i do that without javascript?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
   <img src="..." class="img" />
```

css:

```
.img {
 max-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: max-width in img did not help